# Simple mobile app to Laravel API authentication with Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Laravel 5.6

I need to create a way for the mobile app users to be able to register an account in a Laravel based app and then log in and gain access to the API.

All user data and credentials will be stored in Laravel App. The mobile app will have to be authorised as long as the user doesn't log themselves out manually.

I read about the Resource owner credentials grant and it seems like the only way to use username/password to receive the token. The problem here is that client_secret has to be stored or generated on an mobile app. (?)

Some people use Implicit grant for mobile app but in my case I need to pass username and password and this method does not seem to offer that.

What is the simplest, "best practice" way of implementing this basic functionality using Passport?

Comment: IF the `client_secret` has to be sorted or generated by the mobile app why not when they create their account it sends over the `client_secret`. and sort the client secret with their account information and its a second form of validation as well as their password and you could hash it too

Comment: The issues here is that mobile app will somehow have to provide client_id and client_secret. What if user uninstalls the app or changes the phone? How can I provide client_id and client_secret then?? What I ended up doing today is to create oauth_client for each mobile user, but then I created a middleware which intercepts the request for the token, and looks up the user in the database and fills in the client_id and client_secret itself.